# Working of mysqli, what query returns after execution

Tags: php, mysqli

I am learning Php,pls help here are code lines

`$connection =new mysqli($host,$user,$password,$db) ;`
`$query="SELECT * FROM erp_comments WHERE project_id = '525037b313b43' ";`
`$result=$connection->query($query);`
`if($result->num_rows)`
        `{`
            `$aol=$result->fetch_object();`
        `}`
`echo $aol->column_name;`

program working correctly I want to know

1.what is $result and what it contains.how it working to have a ROW from Database in $aol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is  successful the $result is mysqli_result object.Otherwise it is FALSE
fetch_object method  returns the current row of a result set as an object.
$aol contains the current row as object.